# Varnish remove specific cookies from backend response

Tags: cookies, varnish, varnish-vcl

I need to remove specific cookies from the backend response in varnish.

My backend server sets a bunch of cookies that I don't need and unfortunately I can not control, so I want to delete them.

However I need some of the cookies, so I want to be able to remove cookies by their name.

For example I want to rename a cookie named bad_cookie, but at the same time keep a cookie named good_cookie.

I have found a lot of resources about removing specific request cookies, but none about removing backend response cookies.

Is this possible in Varnish?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to **rename** I think it would be something like:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    #renamed after receiving the backend
    set beresp.http.set-cookie = regsuball(beresp.http.set-cookie, "bad_cookie", "good_cookie"); 
    set beresp.http.cookie = regsuball(beresp.http.cookie, "bad_cookie", "good_cookie"); }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    #renamed before sending the client
    set resp.http.set-cookie = regsuball(beresp.http.set-cookie, "bad_cookie", "good_cookie"); 
    set resp.http.cookie = regsuball(beresp.http.cookie, "bad_cookie", "good_cookie"); }
}
```

If you want to **delete all** cookies:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    #deleted after receiving the backend
    remove beresp.http.set-cookie;
    remove beresp.http.cookie;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    #deleted before sending the client
    remove resp.http.set-cookie;
    remove resp.http.cookie;
}
```

`beresp.http.set-cookie` reads only the **first Set-Cookie header**, If you want to **delete some and keep others** can use: [github.com/varnish/libvmod-header](http://github.com/varnish/libvmod-header)**

Comment: removing beresp.http.set-cookie in vcl_fetch will remove all cookies. It looks like you can not delete some of the response cookies and keep others because remove beresp.http.set-cookie reads only the first Set-Cookie header. Still haven't found a solution

Comment: You are right, for multiple set-cookie headers can use: https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-header

Comment: yeah vmod_header did exactly what I needed... Thanks.

Comment: @MartinTaleski Great! I changed the answer!